# Change bibliography heading (Apacite & Babel)

Tags: bibliographies, babel, apacite

today I tried to set up the latex document for my master thesis and I ran into some troubles with the bibliography. Long story short, I switched to the package Apacite, which provides everything I need. One little thing though. I tried changing the heading of the bibliography from "References" to "Bibliography" but it doesn't work.

```
%Documentclass-------------------------------------------------------------
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%Packages-------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{acro}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[apaciteclassic,sectionbib]{apacite}

%Configuration-------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\acsetup{first-style=short}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{
    \renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}
}

%Document-------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{3}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev,name=List of Abbreviations]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Abbreviations}
\cleardoublepage

\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listfigurename}
\cleardoublepage

\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\listtablename}
\cleardoublepage

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Introduction}

\newpage    
\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{7}
%References-------------------------------------------------------------
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bibliography}

%Appendix-------------------------------------------------------------
\newpage    
\appendix
\section{Title of Appendix A}
\end{document}
```

I'm aware that since I'm using babel I need to surround \renewcommand with \addto{\captionsenglish}{...} which works perfectly to change the heading of my table of contents but it's not working for the bibliography. Can someone provide any help?

Regards,
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to load `babel` *after* `apacite`. (And `apacite` needs to be loaded after `hyperref`; see below.)

```
...
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[apaciteclassic,sectionbib]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addto{\captionsenglish}{%
    \renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}%
    \renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}}
...
```

This issue is mentioned, albeit not all that clearly, on p. 40 of the user guide of the `apacite` package, under the entry `\refname`.

Section 8.2 of the user guide of the `apacite` package provides the following information:

> `apacite` is compatible with `hyperref`, provided that
>   `apacite` is loaded *after* `hyperref`.

Comment: @AlanMunn - Many thanks for pointing this out. I will update my answer right away.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did it. I actually read that document but evidently not carefully enough. Thanks again!