# Changing the bibliography heading style with `apacite` and the `letter` document style

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, apacite

I am writing a letter with an APA-style bibliography, and I want to center the bibliography heading. There are no hooks in `apacite` for controlling its formatting, so I'm going to have to renew `\section` (which isn't defined in the `letter` environment, but which I am defining for the body anyway). So I have written this code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{letter}

\usepackage{microtype}          % better spacing
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % nice margins
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % utf-8 encoding
\usepackage{block}              % left-align everything
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} % citations
\usepackage[english]{babel}     % correct line breaks
\usepackage{setspace}           % double spacing

%\addto{\captionsenglish}{\renewcommand{\refname}{}}
\newcommand{\section}[1]{{\bf #1}\hfill\break}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\doublespacing
\newcommand{\newblock}{}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\begin{center}#1\end{center}}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
\singlespacing

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

But instead of centering my header, it does this:

[image: A centered asterisk appears before the title, but the title itself is not centered.]

What does this mean? How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is obvious once you see it. `apacite` is supplying two arguments to `\section`, one being the asterisk, and the other being the title. (I had my own battles with changing the title; it turned out to be an interaction with the `babel` package, documented [here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366448/change-bibliography-heading-apacite-babel)) So the correct code for the redefinition of `\section` is:

```
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{\begin{center}#2\end{center}}
```